# How do I check day for cross month

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime

I have an activity that only perform in a date range regardless month/year. I need to validate if the current date is >= 30 and <= 05 (next month).

**Sample code below:**

```
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );
$date = substr($d->format("d"),0,2);

if($date >= 30000000 && $date <= 05000000){
    $validate = true;
}
```

I simply cannot use >= 30 and <= 05 as it is an invalid range. Or should I need to code:

```
if($date = 30 || $date = 31 || $date = 01 || $date = 02 || $date = 03 || $date = 04 || $date = 05){
    $validate = true;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `'j'` format specifier instead of `'d'`: `$day = $d->format('j');`. No need for string manipulations.

Comment: You don't need `microtime` for building `DateTime` object for the current date/time. Simply invoke the constructor without arguments: `$d = new DateTime();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think your code is ok. You could do by using timestamps I guess, but a little improvement for your code could be:

```
$dates = array(30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (in_array(((int)$date), $dates)
    $validate = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

## The *Current* Date

> I have an activity that only perform in a date range regardless month/year. I need to validate if the current date is >= 30 and <= 05 (next month).

The *current* date cannot be in the next month by definition. So if you want to check if the current date is between the 1<sup>st</sup> and the 5<sup>th</sup> or is greater than the 30<sup>th</sup>, you can simply fetch the day with `$day = $datetime->format('j')` and check if `$day <= 5` or `$day >= 30`.

To construct a `DateTime` object with the *current* date simply invoke the constructor without arguments. Example:

```
function validate($format = 'now') {
  $now = new DateTime($format);
  $day = $now->format('j');
  return ($day >= 30 || $day <= 5);
}
```

**Testing**

```
// Create DateTime object for the first day of the current month
$d = new DateTime('first day of');
$day_to = (new DateTime())->format('j');

for ($i = 0; $i < $day_to; $i++) {
  printf("%d: %d\n", $i + 1, validate('@' . $d->getTimestamp() . " + $i days"));
}
```

*Output*

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 0
7: 0
...
27: 0
28: 0
29: 0
30: 1
31: 1
```

## Arbitrary Date

If you want to check if a date falls into a range of dates, use the comparison operators on the `DateTime` objects.

In your particular case, you can construct two `DateTime` objects for the range and compare them to any `DateTime` object as in the following example:

```
$d = new DateTime('2017-02-01 20:15');

// 5th day of the next month
$rhd = new DateTime('first day of next month');
$rhd->modify('+4 day');
$rhd->setTime(0, 0, 0);

// 30th day of the current month
$lhd = new DateTime('first day of');
$lhd->modify('+29 day');
$lhd->setTime(0, 0, 0);

printf(
  "%s %s between\n%s and\n%s\n",
  $d->format('r'),
  ($d >= $lhd && $d <= $rhd) ? 'is' : 'is not',
  $lhd->format('r'),
  $rhd->format('r')
);
```

Comment: if the current date is 6th, it would return true isn't it?

Comment: @4LeaveCover, why, no, it will return _false_, because `6 < 30` and `6 > 5`. You can test it with different arguments, e.g. `new DateTime("now + 6 days")`

Comment: I do not upvote because the range I want is (current month)30,31,1,2,3,4,5(next month), not (current month)1,2,3,4,5,30,31(current month). But thank you for your effort.

Comment: @4LeaveCover, the current day cannot be in the next month by definition. In order to check if an arbitrary date is between a range of dates construct `DateTime` objects and compare them using the comparison operators (`>=`, `<=`) as it is shown in the new example.

Comment: @4LeaveCover, by the way, the accepted answer checks the day of the `DateTime` object (i.e. the current one) in a very inefficient _O(n)_ way. You might check if `$day >= 30 or $day <= 5` with the same effect, but more efficiently.